# React PWA: create-react-app using react-router renders 404 page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

***This happens ONLY when I add my PWA to the home screen and run the app from there.*** I'm not seeing this behavior when I run the app on the mobile or desktop browser.

I'm working on a React app built using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/). It works fine after running `npm run build` and serving it using any local http-server. It also seems to work fine once I deploy it to Firebase or `now` and open the site on Firefox or Chrome mobile browsers. However, when I hit the "Add to Homescreen" button on the pop-up, it get's added, but opening it from the homescreen icon renders the 404 route.

I used react-router's `<Switch/>` component to route to a custom 404 page if no path matches the URL. Here's how I defined my Router "configuration":

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
      <Route 
        render={() => (
        <div>
          <h1>Error 404: Not Found</h1>
          <Link to="/">Go Home</Link>
        </div>)}
      />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Versions of packages in my `package.json`:

- `react`: ^16.2.0
- `react-scripts`: 1.1.0
- `react-router-dom`: ^4.2.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason for this is that when the app is opened from the homescreen, it looks for the `./index.html` route mentioned in the `manifest.json` file that is created by create-react-app. This path does not match any of the routes in the router configuration, and so it renders the 404 page. If no 404 page were created, then a blank page would be displayed, since all routes would return null.

You can observe the same behavior if you visit the URL manually on your browser at: https://website.com/index.html. The app will either render a blank page or a 404 page (if you've created one).

In order to fix this, change the `start_url` field in the `manifest.json` file as follows:

```
{
  ...
  start_url: "/"
}
```

Now when the app is started from the homescreen, it will look for the `'/'` path instead of `'/index.html'`.